# Why am i getting an error when declaring variables YAML

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have the code as below which works fine

```
variables:
  - group: docker-settings
```

I need to add a variable to use in a condition so i insert the variable as below but then I get an error? If I remove -group :docker-settings it works, if I remove isMaster line instead it works but it doesnt like them both there? What am I doing wrong?

```
variables:
  - group: docker-settings
  isMaster: $[eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads
```

I used these docs
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

Comment: Please try it with name/value: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#run-if-a-variable-is-null-empty-string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used the `name / value` notation and fixed the value based on the [MS example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops) and set *master* instead of *main*. I guess this is what you want to have.

```yaml
variables:
  - group: docker-settings
  - name: 'isMaster'
    value: $[eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master')]
```

Microsoft example:

```yaml
variables:
  staticVar: 'my value' # static variable
  compileVar: ${{ variables.staticVar }} # compile time expression
  isMain: $[eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/main')] # runtime expression

steps:
  - script: |
      echo ${{variables.staticVar}} # outputs my value
      echo $(compileVar) # outputs my value
      echo $(isMain) # outputs True
```

*Don't give up with yaml and Azure DevOps ;-)*

Comment: Makes sense when you realize the `-` character in yaml means it's an array. You can't start with one syntax and then flip to the other